# Penetration testers say that the .ASPXAUTH cookie is insecure and is displaying session data?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, penetration-testing, .aspxauth

I thought the .ASPXAUTH was for user authentication? Can anyone confirm if this cookie is indeed a security risk and/or contains session information? Is it even suppose to be used or is it some debug thing?

Comment: From question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423467/what-is-aspxauth-cookie - .aspxauth is not session related - it identifies the user.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have run into some comments that have to do with Forms Authentication security. You can find more info here: h[ttp://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/09/14/aspnet-security-hack.aspx](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/09/14/aspnet-security-hack.aspx)

What it boils down to is that a clever hacker can discover the machine key used to encrypt the cookeis and create their own forged auth cookies.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning here that fully patched-up servers no longer exhibit this vulnerability: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/MS10-070

Comment: Actually they couldn't discover the machine key per se. They used the server`s error messages to use the server as a padding oracle. Using the oracle and brute-force they could encrypt any string, one bit at a time. By constructing an encrypted request for the `web.config`. By default this doesn't contain the machinekey; by default it is generated per app in process, unless you generate and configure a key yourself.  Leaking `web.config` is still a Bad Thing™, though.