# SignalR serverSentEvents on Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7 POST request taking too much time to complete

Tags: iis-7, signalr, signalr-hub, server-sent-events, postdelayed

I'm using [`SignalR 2.0.0-beta2`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) and it's behaving strangely in production environment where an `ASP.NET MVC 5` [ .NET Framework 4.5 ] app is installed on `Windows Server 2008` with `IIS 7`. The AppPool is in Integrated Mode and only has this app.

The `GET` request made by `SignalR` takes only **60 ms**:

```
http://mysite.org.br/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&_=1374377239338
```

The problem happens with the `POST` request that takes forever. In the most recent test right now it took incredible **3m 1s**:

```
http://mysite.org.br/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=Lp%2BGdI6jVTLPrQ3ZGJ065F9GrMbKYWNmgrtKPZz%2BCUYAsxrqP7hyAMPr%2Bg1E3IRY%2F0brzXVanumPy7NPCFOlcXTRrJssFD2EEoxd6fWhAVEUSfIj
```

When this intermittent problem happens it generally takes more than ***40 seconds*** to complete the request.

Testing it with `Firefox 22` and Firebug... if I disable *browser cache*, it runs smoothly, that is, there's no delay it the `POST` request. Otherwise, when I enable browser cache, it delays again the `POST` request.

Using `Google Chrome 28` the POST sits there with a *pending* status.

If I recycle the `AppPool`, then the `POST` request takes only **203 ms**.
The only modification I did to this specific `AppPool` was that I set `Idle Time-out (minutes) = 0`, that is, I'd like to avoid recycling the AppPool.

Looking at Process Explorer I see that [`w3wp.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/w3wp/info) has `177.300 KB (Private Bytes)` and `211.900 (Working Set)` and `CPU` is `0` right now.

Here's `SignalR` log information taken from Firebug console:

```
[00:27:20 GMT-0300] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3'.
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
GET http://mysiste.org.br/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&_=1374377239338 200 OK 62ms  
js?v=K...xUBM641 (line 1)
[00:27:20 GMT-0300] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://mysiste.org.br/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=Lp%2BGdI6jVTLPrQ3ZGJ065F9GrMbKYWNmgrtKPZz%2BCUYAsxrqP7hyAMPr%2Bg1E3IRY%2F0brzXVanumPy7NPCFOlcXTRrJssFD2EEoxd6fWhAVEUSfIj&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22assessmenthub%22%7D%5D&tid=5'
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:27:20 GMT-0300] SignalR: EventSource connected
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:27:20 GMT-0300] SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
POST http://mysiste.org.br/signalr/send?transport=s...F0brzXVanumPy7NPCFOlcXTRrJssFD2EEoxd6fWhAVEUSfIj 200 OK 3m 1s 
js?v=K...xUBM641 (line 1)
[00:39:12 GMT-0300] SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:12 GMT-0300] SignalR: EventSource reconnecting due to the server connection ending
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:14 GMT-0300] SignalR: EventSource calling close()
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:14 GMT-0300] SignalR: serverSentEvents reconnecting
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:14 GMT-0300] SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint 'http://mysiste.org.br/signalr/reconnect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=Lp%2BGdI6jVTLPrQ3ZGJ065F9GrMbKYWNmgrtKPZz%2BCUYAsxrqP7hyAMPr%2Bg1E3IRY%2F0brzXVanumPy7NPCFOlcXTRrJssFD2EEoxd6fWhAVEUSfIj&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22assessmenthub%22%7D%5D&messageId=d-k%2C0%7Cx%2C0%7Cy%2C1%7Cz%2C0&tid=5'
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:44 GMT-0300] SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (30000ms), disconnecting.
Signal...FCU9MU1 (line 1)
[00:39:44 GMT-0300] SignalR: SignalR: Stopping connection.
```

My `Web.config` has these settings:

```
<system.web>
.
.
.
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
         </providers>
    </sessionState>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="PerRequestLifestyle" type="Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle.PerWebRequestLifestyleModule, Castle.Windsor" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="AttributeRouting" path="routes.axd" verb="*" type="AttributeRouting.Web.Logging.LogRoutesHandler, AttributeRouting.Web" />
  </handlers>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxQueryString="10240"></requestLimits>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

From the symptom looks like the response is being buffered somehow. This [SignalR issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/266) mentions AVG antivirus being the problem, but I do not have AVG antivirus installed on my client's server. It has `McAfee` though.

What can be causing this behavior? If you need any more info to help debug this further, please just ask and I'll do my best to provide it.

---

Note: in the meantime I reverted back to SignalR stable release 1.1.2 and everything is working fine so far.

Comment: Are you using session?

Comment: @dfowler: check the updated `Web.config` settings with `sessionState` info if that's what you mean by `session`.

Comment: Using session with SignalR won't work at all. It'll make all requests take the session lock and that's likely why you're seeing these problems.

Comment: @dfowler: see that it's `InProc`... is it still an impediment? Is something related to this described on `SignalR` docs?

Comment: I use `ASP.NET Forms Authentication` and thought that I needed the `InProc` session state because of its cookie. Looks like it's not necessary at all: http://stackoverflow.com/a/424061/114029 So if I remove it, SignalR should work as expected? I hope so... as I'm really not using Session anywhere in the app.

Comment: Yep, remove session and remove the session events from Global.asax and it should work.

Comment: @dfowler Nice my brother! Thanks for your attention and for making this extraordinary/AWESOME library. You from Microsoft ROCK the World!

Comment: @dfowler: this hanging problem started again... why? This time I don't have any session in `Web.config` and nothing related to Session in Global.asax. I'm using 2.0.0-rc1. If I recycle the AppPool then it start working again. This is the URL that hangs forever: `http://mysite.org.br/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=ZR86rSYlXJMiMkdI%2FZrZj8TkyDv5DVTDqTundsghIFy7Umvc0yqmzKkEI79K6BAMrgpWTGpjiI8%2Bax4UM2jaBRVNhbXb9XzZpzjdJZzS6NHGwpc2&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22assessmenthub%22%7D%5D`

Comment: Update to SignalR 2.0.0

Comment: @dfowler It's working great now after updating to 2.0.0. :)

Comment: @dfowler: how do you mean no sessions at all? A web application that uses sessions (e.g. for storing user related info after login), can not use signalr without this kind of latency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to make this clear for everyone that might find this problem in the future:

The problem is related to [`SessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) used in ASP.NET. As [@dfowler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45091/dfowler) said:

> Using session with SignalR won't work at all. It'll make all requests
>   take the session lock and that's likely why you're seeing these
>   problems.

So, the solution is: remove the `<sessionState>` config from your `Web.config` file and any session events you might have in your `Global.asax`.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

After getting rid of it the problem was solved in my case.

---

**I had to update to [SignalR 2.0.0](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.0.0) to really fix the issue.**