# Where does the user information in Server Variables come from in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

In the Server Variables collection I note there are:

```
REMOTE_USER
LOGON_USER
AUTH_USER
```

Do these come from the decypted ".ASPXFORMSAUTH" cookie?

EDIT:

Think I am correct:

```
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//.ASPXAUTH
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

Reference : [what is ASPXAUTH cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423467/what-is-aspxauth-cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Think I am correct:

```
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];//.ASPXAUTH
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
```

Reference : [what is ASPXAUTH cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423467/what-is-aspxauth-cookie)